# What do I need in my script to be able to change ownership of a directory structure that belongs to root to the current user running the bash script?

Tags: shell-script, su, chown

My bash script has the following section:

```
su root -c chown -R smithb:other /export/home/smithb/workspace/rootownsit/
exit
```

The directory `rootownsit` and its two sub directories were created and is owned by `root`. I thought what I have above would work but it doesn't. Running my bash script as my user, I get prompted for the root password and then I get a usage message for `chown` after I type in the root password. I need to change ownership of the directory rootownsit and it's sub directories.

Comment: What's the error message? Without quotes I get `su: invalid option -- 'R'`. With quotes like `su root -c 'chown -R smithb:other /export/home/smithb/workspace/rootownsit/'` it seems to work

Comment: I get: "usage: chown [-fhR] owner[:group] file... chown -R [-f] [-H|-L|-P] owner[:group] file..." Oh so I should try quotes??

Comment: @user000001 It worked with quotes!! But my script seems to stop right after that...

Comment: Ok found my other issue - I had `exit` direclty after the `su` command because I thought I would need to do that. Does that mean the rest of my script execution is under root? How do I get back to the current user account??

Comment: Only the current command will be executed as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple syntax problem. `su` takes a single (optional) command argument, which is parsed by the target user's login shell. Here, the command you're running as root is the argument of `-c`, which is just `chown`. Put the command in quotes in your script so that it becomes a single argument.

```
su -c 'chown -R smithb:other /export/home/smithb/workspace/rootownsit/' root
```

The built-in command `exit` exits the script; if you don't want that to happen, don't call `exit`.